# When to allow Services to access the IoC Controller?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

What are the scenarios in which it's OK to allow services created via IoC to have access back to the IoC controller to access other services? It seems to me that the short answer is never, but are there situations in which it's OK or even in which it makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean by 'services'? Try to give an example or scenario which better describes what you're trying to accomplish. What you're asking right now is rather vague...

Comment: Do you mean passing the IoC container around to the services (i.e. using the container as a service locator)?

Comment: (Ab)using an IoC container as a service locator is only acceptable if you write a framework (not some small helper class library but something substantial like [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com)) that must be container agnostic. Then the service locator is an additional layer of indirection that hides the specific container and does not enforce users of the framework to follow the DI pattern.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is 'never', since it sounds like what you describe is service locator, [which is an anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)

Comment: +1. The only sensible place to call the container is inside the composition root.

Answer (score 0):

There's a rather well written article about this from Martin Fowler:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator

> A lot of this depends on the nature of the user of the service. If you
>   are building an application with various classes that use a service,
>   then a dependency from the application classes to the locator isn't a
>   big deal. In my example of giving a Movie Lister to my friends, then
>   using a service locator works quite well. All they need to do is to
>   configure the locator to hook in the right service implementations,
>   either through some configuration code or through a configuration
>   file. In this kind of scenario I don't see the injector's inversion as
>   providing anything compelling.